# Can't copy unicode for a blank name in among us

Tags: among-us

I have a really old tablet, so that could be a reason, but I just can't seem to be able to copy and paste the U+3164   Unicode to have a blank name in among us, and I don't know why I can't use it, forcing me to change my name to a fake version (U 3164) of the Unicode, since special symbols (+,_,!) can't be typed into the player name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you figure it out, you cannot copy and paste your name to be blank on Among Us, because it has a new name change location, and the Among Us servers deny usernames like this.

According to [Shacknews,](https://www.shacknews.com/article/120583/how-to-get-a-blank-name-among-us) even in the last update, you still cannot have a blank name:

> While you can no longer have a blank name in Among Us, you can have a dot as your name, which is still pretty sneaky. ... To get a dot as your name, you will need to copy-paste the special Unicode character below: Copy the dot between the quotation marks “ㆍ” Select the name field in Local or Online.

So you can go to the website and copy the punctuation and insert it into Among Us.